# How can you change the mouse cursor in OS X?

Tags: snow-leopard, mouse

I can't find many solutions for changing the mouse cursor on OS X 10.6

I've seen http://unsanity.com/haxies/mightymouse but it does not support 10.6 at the moment.

Any hints or tricks to change the cursor? Specifically, I need to modify the text selection cursor as it is almost invisible when using a grey background in my IDE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, Apple doesn't allow people to change the mouse cursor anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've filed a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com .  I suggest everyone else with this problem do so too :)

Comment: can you provide or some reference regarding this?  thanks in advance

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, it's less "allow" and more "changed the implementation and nobody's figured out how to hack it yet".

Comment: I just field a bug for this. This is annoying.

Comment: I know this is old but my son just changed the icon on our brand new macbook pro (catalina 10.15.6) to a dog and he can't recall how and I can't find a way to change it back. Help!

Comment: Mousescape even works with Ventura now in 2023.

Comment: @Cajunluke: OP does not ask how to do it *without* a third-party app, so the answer is technically wrong and should be removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Use Mousecape. I'm currently using version 0.0.5.

1. Download the program ([version 0.0.5](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases/tag/0.0.5))
2. Double-click the program
3. Make a new mouse cape (cmd + n or by menus)
4. Drag image files on to each new pointer, choose what type of pointer
5. Move the Hot Spot to correctly register clicks

[image]

I suggest getting images from free icon libraries. Google search or something. I downloaded some free icons and edited them.

You can use custom capes that others have made but the only one I've found is the one included in the source code. To get it, download the source and find the .cape file in it. Simple drag and drop the file into the program.

You can download the source code, etc, [on github](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape).

Comment: i just tried it, and this works great on 10.10

Comment: Download app in Release page: https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple options:

In System Preferences > Universal Access > Mouse pane, there is a control to change the size of the cursor.

Mouseposé is an application that supports Snow Leopard used mostly for presentations and recording demos. You can set up a hotkey that dims the screen puts a spotlight on the current cursor position so you can find it quickly.

Comment: On 10.10.5 Yosemite, it's System Preferences > Acccessibility > Mouse & Trackpad, but there's no longer a control to change the cursor size.

Answer (score 2):

[Mousecape](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape) does a great job. It is almost completely undocumented, sub-1.0 release, and doesn't really come with any cursors. Still worth a look!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/) and leave it on or turn it on via a hotkey when you need to find your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is "System Preferences" -> "Accessibility" -> "Display" -> "Cursor".

Inside the cursor tab you are table to change the size.  You can't do any other customization than size but its a good start.

[image]

Comment: But the OP wants to change the colour. How does this answer help?